# Magento 2.2.0 Custom Shipping module - Not Working as expected

Tags: magento2

I have created a custom shipping module which calculate the rate according to ordered products weight and selected location(postcode).

There are 3 weights:

- 1: small
- 2: medium
- 3: large

Locations: 
for locations : 'V' and 'W', The shipping rate is as follow:

- 1: small weight: 5
- 2: medium weight: 10
- 3: large weight: 12

for locations : 'X' and 'Y', The shipping rate is as follow:

- 1: small weight: 15
- 2: medium weight: 40
- 3: large weight: 50

The modules gets all order items then it gets the largest weight. After that it gets the corresponding rate.

The postcode is dropdown on checkout page, When user changes postcode, magento recalculates shipping rate and print the rate in two places:

- under shipping method
  [image]
- In Order Review[image]

The logic is working fine in order review, however the rate is not updated as expected under shipping address. If user chooses location V for medium weight item, Both rates updated successfully on checkout to 10, but if he changes the location to location Y, the rate in order review changes to 40 but in shipping method **remains the same**.

Here is the logic

```
 public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
{
    /**
     * Make sure that Shipping method is enabled
     */
    if (!$this->isActive()) {
        return false;
    }

    /** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result */
    $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();
    $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();
    /**
     * Set carrier's method data
     */
    $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
    $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
    /**
     * Displayed as shipping method under Carrier
     */

     /**
     * Get Order Items
     */
    $items = $request->getAllItems();
    $postcode = $request->getDestPostcode();


    $method->setMethod($this->_code);
    $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

    $weight = 1;

    /**
     * set Weight to the largest item weight
     * 1:small, 2:medium, 3:large
     */
    foreach ($items as $_item) {
        if ($weight < $_item->getWeight()) {
            $weight = $_item->getWeight();
        }
    }

    $cityCharges = [
        [
            'city' => [
                'V',
                'W'
            ],
            'charge' => [
                'price_small' => 5,
                'price_medium' => 10,
                'price_large' => 12,
            ]
        ],
        [
            'city' => [
                'X',
                'Y',
            ],
            'charge' => [
                'price_small' => 15,
                'price_medium' => 40,
                'price_large' => 50,
            ]
        ],
        [
            'city' => [
                'Z'
            ],
            'charge' => [
                'price_small' => 5,
                'price_medium' => 10,
                'price_large' => 50,
            ]
        ],
    ];

    $selectedChargesList = null;

    foreach ($cityCharges as $cityCharge) {
        if (in_array($postcode, $cityCharge['city'])) {
            $selectedChargesList = $cityCharge['charge'];
        }
    }

    switch ($weight) {
        case 1:
            $price = $selectedChargesList['price_small'];
            break;
        case 2:
            $price = $selectedChargesList['price_medium'];
            break;
        case 3:
            $price = $selectedChargesList['price_large'];
            break;
    }

    $method->setPrice($price);
    $method->setCost($price);
    $result->append($method);

    return $result;
}


protected function getCurrentQuote($quoteId)
{
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $quoteFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory');
    return $quoteFactory->create()->load($quoteId);
}
```

I think the problem is with this :

https://www.example.com/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/xxxxxxxxx/estimate-shipping-methods

however https://www.example.com/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/xxxxxxxxx/shipping-information is getting the correct rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found it.

This Ajax was returning an error: 
https://www.example.com/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/xxxxxxxxx/estimate-shipping-methods

```
Unable to save address. Please check input data
```

After Search, I have added the following to .htaccess and then flushed magento cache:

```
php_value include_path "."
```

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11185#issuecomment-405069085)

http://prntscr.com/k6lo2q

Now **estimate-shipping-methods** ajax call is getting the values and is updating them on checkout form.